# How do manipulate list of objects by date parameters in a hashmap?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have a hashmap with key and object like

> HashMap<String,List<Object,> > profileMap=   new HashMap<>();
> ArrayList eventList = new ArrayList();

> for(Profile profile:Plist) {
> >         profileMap.putIfAbsent(profile.getprofileID(),eventList );
> cpToEvent.get(event.getContact_profile()).add(event);
> }

Profile object contains information about different events, event date, and profileID associated with that event.

I need to delete the events of the profile where the gap between two events in a profile is more than 1 yrs.

For that, I need to sort the list so that I can calculate the gap between them before deleting them.
How do achieve this?

Comment: what type is ListObj? Is obj.getDate() returning a Date? Or a LocalDate? Or... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to share more information. So far your data does not seem to contain any date.

Comment: ListObj is a list of profile object. profile contains information on multiple events for a profile with event date.  i need to delete older events if the gap between two events is more than 1 year.

Comment: So, I am trying to sort the list of objects using the date. so that i can calculate gap between two events.

Comment: @UjjwalKuikel then isn't the fact that you have a `Map` irrelevant? You can sort each profile's events independently, no? And the filtering logic is for "filtering out events older than 1 year from some fixed date (e.g. today)", as in the question, or "if the gap between consecutive events is larger than 1 year", as in the comment above?

Comment: How many elements do you have in the `Map` and and in the `List`? Can you filter the `List` in-place or do you need a new `List` with just the sorted and filtered data?

Comment: For each profile, there are multiple events. I need to check the gap between events belonging to the same profile only, So the map is used for that. Or, is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Can you suggest a way to sort each profile's event independently?

Comment: There can be 1000 of elements in the map and each element may contain 5-10 events in the list

Comment: Please specify the logic for going from one list of events to the final one you seek, because it is not clear. With examples, if possible. And rephrase your question to be about manipulating the `List`, unless you have issues with applying the same processing for each element in the `Map` (since each profile is independent)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have the elements in your List sorted, I recommend using a natively existing type such as a "SortedSet" implementation. E.g. a TreeSet

```
Map<String, TreeSet<Object>> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
```

This will have you implementing the Comparator Interface in which you can define to sort by Date.

```
public class Objekt implements Comparator<Objekt> {

@Override
public int compare(Objekt o1, Objekt o2) {
    if (o1.getDate().before(o2.getDate())) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o1.getDate().after(o2.getDate())) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

More on how to implement that here: [Compare Object by dates ( implements Comparator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424526/compare-object-by-dates-implements-comparator)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate over the HashMap item and filter the element with Date that is older than 1 year.

Given the Profile class as below

```
public class Profile {

private Date createdAt;

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}
```

}

And our List is

```
HashMap<String, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<>();
```

Then we can simply do as below to get the list of Map.Entry that matches your requirement.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Profile>> matchProfile = profiles.entrySet().stream().filter(item -> item.getValue().getCreatedAt().getYear() > 2015)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several constraints you should have in mind, mostly regarding modifying your existing objects.

The simplest code that processes your items is this:

```
    Map<String, List<Profile>> profileMap= ...;

    profileMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        v.sort(Comparator.comparing(Profile::getDate));
        // additional processing on "v" here (v is the value in the Map.Entry, i.e. the list of profiles)
    });
```

But the code above modifies the `List` which exists in your map.

If you need to preserve the existing `List` as-is, then instead of sorting `v`, you should create a new `List` and then process that.

```
    profileMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>(e.getValue());
        profiles.sort(Comparator.comparing(Profile::getDate));
        e.setValue(profiles);
    });
```

The code above modifies the `profileMap`, it now maps the original keys to new values.

Again, if that is not ok, and you want to preserve the original `profileMap` entirely, then in the `forEach` above you need to fill a new `Map` instead of `setValue`-ing the existing entries.

Make sure to focus on solving or improving the overall product, not just on a small piece of the processing. Sometimes, the best way to improving a process is to eliminate some parts of it entirely and adjust the remaining pieces.

Why do you have a huge list of events that is both unsorted and containing obsolete entries? Can you sort the events when receiving them? Or when reading them from the database?